# Login check in FosUserBundle & FacebookBundle. Asks for overrided method

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

So here I have, my totally configured fos&face environment. I took step by step tutorial within these two bundles, checked hundred of times, ane nothing....

What is a problem? My fosBundle works great (have my own model class and my own facebook provider). The problem appears, when I try to login via facebook by clicking the famous blue button. I click, sth is opening, then close -> and error (in redirection).
that action /check_login is returning anything. I haven't done anything with that action (took step by step, like I said) and in config there is no word mentioning editing routing /check_login.

After all, facebookBundle doesn't work at all for me, because the lack of this action.

Can sb help me out?

Some config info:

```
fosbundle: ~2.0@dev
facebookbundle: dev-master
```

security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
          providers: [fos_userbundle, my_fos_facebook_provider]
    fos_userbundle:
        id: user_provider
    my_fos_facebook_provider:
        id: my.facebook.user   # see "Example Custom User Provider using the FOS\UserBundle" chapter further down

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
    public:
        pattern:   ^/.*
        fos_facebook:
            app_url: "http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=myAppId"
            server_url: "http://l.local/app_dev.php/"
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /
            provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
        anonymous: true
        logout: true
        #            redirect_to_facebook_login: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/secured/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
    - { path: ^/facebook/,  role: [ROLE_FACEBOOK] }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
```

config.yml
     ....

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: propel # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Back\UserBundle\Model\User

fos_facebook:
    alias:  <name>
    app_id: <myNumber>
    secret: <myNumber>
    cookie: true
    permissions: [email]
```

routing.yml

```
fos_facebook_channel:
    resource: "@FOSFacebookBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

_imagine:
     resource: .
     type:     imagine

_security_check:
     pattern:  /login_check

_security_logout:
     pattern:  /logout
```

Hope, these info are enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the FB provider as a service. In the main `config.yml` or in the bundle `services.yml`

```
services:
  my.facebook.user:
      class: Demo\UserBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
      arguments:
          facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
          userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
          validator: "@validator"
```

In your `security.yml` change the `check_path` parameter for facebook to something different. 
`check_path: /login_facebook_check` 
And in the `routing.yml`

```
security:
  encoders:
      FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

  role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
      ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

  providers:
      chain_provider:
         chain:
             providers: fos_user_bundle,my_fos_facebook_provider
      fos_user_bundle:
             id: fos_user.user_provider.username
      my_fos_facebook_provider:
             id: my.facebook.user   


  firewalls:
      main:
          pattern: ^/
          form_login:
              provider: fos_user_bundle
              csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
              login_path: /login
              check_path: /login_check
          fos_facebook:
              app_url: " xxx "
              server_url: "xxx"
              check_path: /login_fb_check
              default_target_path: /
              provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
         logout: true
         anonymous:    true

  access_control:
      - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And my full `routing.yml`

```
demo_user:
  resource: "@DemoUserBundle/Controller/"
  type:     annotation
  prefix:   /


_security_check:
   pattern:   /login_fb_check

_security_logout:
   pattern:  /logout



fos_user_security:
   resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
   resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
   prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
   resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
   prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
  prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
  resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
  prefix: /profile
```

Comment: Your way does not work. Still same error. It asks me everytime same thing: 
`Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration`

Comment: In the form login add the `login_path: /login` and               `check_path: /login_check` I edited my security.yml

Comment: I need to be sure if my routes and security names are good, cause, sometimes u write `/login_fb_check` and other time `_facebook_login_check`.

Comment: Please paste your `routing.yml`
My controller asks for `_facebook_login_check` method.

Comment: `/login_fb_check` is the route and `_facebook_login_check` is the name of the route. I will post my full routing.yml

Comment: Ok, but how about the controller to `/login_fb_check` ?

Comment: There is no controller for the login_fb_check. I've managed to reproduce your error message. I am posting the working routing.yml shotly

Comment: And you have no controller for `/login_fb_check`?

Comment: Now I have this kind of error `You are not allowed to define new elements for path "security.firewalls". Please define all elements for this path in one config file.`

Comment: Problem was in my config, cause I had two firewalls. It needs to be one. "public". Then SF catches the request. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. See also this gist  for setting up FOSUserBundle with HWIOauthBundle https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697